# The best way to configurate the baseUrl for multiple js file

Tags: javascript, production

I am writing a hybrid app, there are several separate html/js would be loaded into different Android webviews.

For debugging, I have to change the base Url for my ajax request, due to the different network connection, different co-workers...

But the different urls are in many JS files.

```
//file1.js
baseUrl = "192.168.1.114:3000";


//file2.js
baseUrl = "192.168.1.114:3000";


//file3.js
// there are the same baseUrl;
```

I would like to configure and modify all of these fields at the same time for production or debugging. How? Having a Grunt? or Ajax a configuration file before ajax other url?

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you heard of `global` variable ?

Comment: use `window["baseurl"]` .

Comment: All these `js` are working in a separate webview, I don't think they will share the variables.

Comment: use `localStorage` is accessible ? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I agree with @RayonDabre why don't use global variables or better objects to define configuration.. maybe create a configuration file that is accessible to all webviews

Comment: `localStorage` should work. But before I run my project, I have to run a configuration like `config.js` to rewrite all my `localStorage` variables. It looks a little bit weird. And I don't think it would work when it is running on `file://`.

Comment: probably a deploy tool or task runner would help me out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches and it's impossible to decide what is better because the best solution resides always in the middle...

For example, doing that via build-tools (grunt, gulp, ecc...), gives you the ability to work with different configurations trasparently, but, you lose the ability to switch **ENV** at **runtime**...

How I can test staging domains in production environments?

---

So, my experience says that the best solution is to create an hybrid system, for example:

Via *grunt-contrib-uglify* (for example), at the **compilation time**, you can pass all (or just importants) configurations available and, using another variable called ENV (`var ENV = 'PRODUCTION')` you can let your application decide which of them use...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, modify it at compilation time. But what I really don't like the compilation, because it will create another compiled `js` and increase the complexity of the project. I have to deal with the `jsx` compiler and `grunt` compiler at the same time now...

Comment: Of course everything you put in your project increases the complexity, compilers are useful for code optimization, error preventing and something else but they need to be managed, now and in the future...

Answer (score 0):

**The Lifetime of JavaScript Variables**

- The lifetime of a JavaScript variable starts when it is declared.
- Local variables are deleted when the function is completed.
- Global variables are deleted when you close the page.

Use global variable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If using JS is getting monotonous, try [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element. It's not as flexible as global variables (unless you don't mind altering `href`attribute), it's more as a convenience.

Just so I won't be downvoted for not conforming to the OPs tags...

```
var base = document.querySelector('base');
base.href = "http://192.168.1.114";
```

Comment: Do I have to change all the <base> field in each HTML file?

Comment: Yeah, it's the first element in the `<head>`, and there's only 1 required attribute: `<base href="http://192.168.0"/>` the `target` attribute is optional. I doesn't even have a tag end. It saves you from having to use a ton of absolute URLs.

Comment: I re-read your question, and actually it's no you don't have to change the base element for every page. You can have a different base for each file, or just some pages or none at all, but it's limited to one per page.